# GrapeCity ActiveReports HTML5 Viewer Passing Parameters to Report Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting, activereports

I want to pass the parameters through my MVC view to report parameters in active reports html5 viewer, but i am not able to do that.

here is my code:

```
 var reportOption =   {
            id: 'AR_HTML5Viewer_MVC.Reports.CoolReport.FooReport',
            parameters: [
            {
                name: 'CustomerID',
                value: 'ALFKI'
            }]
        };
```

viewer.option('report', reportOption);

how i give parameter to my report constructor.
my report constructor looks like this:

public FooReport()
        {

```
        var id = Parameters["CustomerID"]; // id is null 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

any help would be appreciated!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track - this would be the correct syntax for sending a parameter value to the report:

```
var reportOption = {
    id: target.attr('data-bind’),
    parameters: [{ name: "parameter1"}]
};
reportsButtons.prop('disabled’, true);
reportOption.parameters[0].value = "ALFKI";
```

Comment: i am using AR 8.2.492.0, i am not able to get parameters in my report. my problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

i updated my AR version to Version=8.2.514.0, and replaced my htmlviewer js with the sample project htmlviewer js which came from update in "my documents" now i am able to get parameters in my report constructor.
thanks for your help!